# How to run JMeter WebDriver sampler script in CentOS?

Tags: jmeter, centos, webdriver

How to run JMeter WebDriver sampler script in CentOS 7.0? I am running in non GUI mode. Should I install any browser?

Currently the script is in Windows OS where I am running with chromedriver and which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to install Chrome browser itself using [yum](https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum) - CentOS Package Manager. In order to do this create i.e. `chrome.repo` file under `/etc/yum.repos.d` with the following contents:

   ```
   [chrome]
   name=chrome
   baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/$basearch
   enabled=1
   gpgcheck=1
   gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
   ```

   once done you will be able to install Chrome using the following command:

   ```
   yum install google-chrome-stable
   ```
2. Next you need to install a [virtual framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) software which will emulate display so you could run your Chrome normally on a system which doesn't have a GUI
       yum install Xvfb
3. Launch Xvfb

   ```
   Xvfb :0 >& /dev/null &
   ```
4. Set DISPLAY variable:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   ```
5. Download ChromeDriver for Linux, from the [ChromeDriver downloads page](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) choose the desired version and fetch `chromedriver_linux64.zip` file. Example command:

   ```
   curl -O https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/chromedriver_linux64.zip
   ```
6. Unpack the ChromeDriver:

   ```
   unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
   ```
7. Set `webdriver.chrome.driver` system property to point to the `chromedriver` binary location under `system.properties` in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
8. Now you can run your WebDriver tests normally

If you need more information refer to the [Headless Execution of Selenium Tests in Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-execution-selenium-tests-jenkins) article